# KSQLDB coalesce always returns null despite parameters

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have the following ksql query:

```
SELECT 
  event->acceptedevent->id as id1, 
  event->refundedevent->id as id2, 
  coalesce(event->acceptedevent->id, event->refundedevent->id) as coalesce_col 
FROM events 
EMIT CHANGES;
```

Based on the documentation, (https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/scalar-functions/#coalesce) `COALESCE` returns the first non-null parameter.

Query returns the following:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
|ID1                                            |ID2                                            |COALESCE_COL                                   |
+-----------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
|1                                              |null                                           |null                                           |
|2                                              |null                                           |null                                           |
|3                                              |null                                           |null                                           |
```

I was expecting since ID1 is clearly not null, being the first parameter to the call, COALESCE will return same value as ID1 but it returns null. What am I missing?

I am using **confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:6.1.1** and use **avro** for the value serde.

EventMessage.avsc:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "EventMessage",
  "namespace": "com.example.poc.processor2.avro",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "event",
      "type": [
        "com.example.poc.processor2.avro.AcceptedEvent",
        "com.example.poc.processor2.avro.RefundedEvent"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What version of ksqlDB are you running?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I am using confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:6.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bug in how data is deserialized, or the COALESCE function.

- What KSQL version are you running
- How is your data serialized in the topic?

I tried with a JSON format and it worked.

```
ksql> describe events;

Name                 : EVENTS
 Field | Type                                                                       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 EVENT | STRUCT<ACCEPTEDEVENT STRUCT<ID INTEGER>, REFUNDEDEVENT STRUCT<ID INTEGER>> 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ksql> print 'events' from BEGINNING;
Key format: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ - no data processed
Value format: JSON or KAFKA_STRING
rowtime: 2021/03/24 13:57:27.403 Z, key: <null>, value: {"event":{"acceptedevent":{"id":1}, "refundedevent":{}}}, partition: 


ksql> select event->acceptedevent->id, event->refundedevent->id, coalesce(event->acceptedevent->id, event->refundedevent->id) from events emit changes;
+----------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|ID                                                        |ID_1                                                      |KSQL_COL_0                                                |
+----------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|1                                                         |null                                                      |1                                                         |
```

Comment: I am using confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:6.1.1 and use avro for the value serde.